# Does an HTable increment consider the auto-flush setting?

Tags: performance, hbase

I'm trying to improve Hbase throughput for increments.  Is it possible to "buffer" several increments (for different rows) by setting [autoflush](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HTable.html#setAutoFlush%28boolean%29) to false and then call [flushCommits](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HTable.html#flushCommits%28%29)?  Or Does the autoflush setting only apply to normal Puts?

Comment: As far as I know autoflash only applies for puts. It doesn't apply for Increments / Deletes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

autoflush doesn't affect increments currently. I would suggest checking out these patches time to time: [HBASE-2947](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-2947) , [HBASE-2814](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-2814) (I am waiting for it aswell). Other than that you can check [asych hbase client](https://github.com/stumbleupon/asynchbase) from stumbleupon.